# click event is not fired when height / content is jumping

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onclick

I have a form with shows validation errors below its fields. It shows validation errors on `blur` event. The problem is that links below this form are not clickable if error message is shown at the time I click a link. The issue is related to the fact that the actual link is going down after error message is injected in dom and position of the click event is not over the link any more

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required>
    <div style="color:red; margin-top: 20px" ng-if="myForm.firstName.$touched && myForm.firstName.$invalid">
      Required field
    </div>
  </form>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Static link</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="linkClick()">Click Me</a>

angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = 'test';
    $scope.linkClick = function(){
      alert('link click');
    }
  }]);
```

[Example Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q40jKP8wJnZKuq9e8wV3?p=preview)

To reproduce an issue, delete input text and click the link (to trigger blur event). It won't show alert. if you click second time - it will.

How to make it work in generic way (every page using a form) that every time I click a link (or anything else) this click event would fire regardless content jumping

Comment: it is possible that you shows error message second side of textbox ?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to do it without redoing the layout of all forms. Also our website is responsive so it might be not so easy to ensure content never jumps

Comment: this is good way if you prefer it and also you can display all error after submit button.

Answer (score 0):

This is because blur happens before the click event.  The order of events is:

- mousedown
- blur
- mouseup
- click

This gets even more interesting if you take keyboard events into effect (i.e. someone tabs away from the input field)

The keyboard order of events for a tab key is:

- keydown
- blur
- keyup

(you also have a keypress event for other keys besides tab)

Therefore you have two solutions:

1. change the click event to a mousedown and keydown event.
2. add a delay of 1000 ms on the blur event before populating the error message.

I like #2 better since I don't have to worry about separate keydown events if I can still use click.

Here is some code for you to play with (all vanilla JS):

```js
var testForm = document.getElementById('testForm'),
    testInput = document.getElementById('testInput'),
    testButton = document.getElementById('testButton'),
    testError = document.createElement("DIV"),
    errorText = document.createTextNode("Error Message");

testInput.addEventListener('blur', function (evt) {
  console.log('blur');
  /*
  if (testInput.value === '') {
    console.log('add div');
    testError.appendChild(errorText);
    testForm.appendChild(testError);
  }
  */
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout ended');
    if (testInput.value === '') {
      console.log('add div');
      testError.appendChild(errorText);
      testForm.appendChild(testError);
    }
  }, 1000);
});

testButton.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
  console.log('mousedown');
});

testButton.addEventListener('mouseup', function (evt) {
  console.log('mouseup');
});

testButton.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  console.log('click');
  alert('you clicked me');
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
  console.log('keydown');
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
  console.log('keyup');
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
  console.log('keypress');
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="testForm">
  <input type="text" value="test" id="testInput" />
</form>
<button id="testButton">TEST BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: In a context of angular, is there a way to easily apply timeout solution for blur? I've tried debounce: 1000 on ng-model-options but it didn't change anything

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular  version 1.58